# How to convert a complete JSON form into XML

Tags: python, json, xml

**If I have the following code and want to convert to XML:**
Note: I tried using json2xml, but it doesn't convert the complete set, rather just converts a segment of it.

```
{
  "odoo": {
    "data": {
      "record": [
        {
          "model": "ir.ui.view",
          "id": "lab_tree_view",
          "field": [
            {
              "name": "name",
              "#text": "human.name.tree"
            },
            {
              "name": "model",
              "#text": "human.name"
            },
            {
              "name": "priority",
              "eval": "16"
            },
            {
              "name": "arch",
              "type": "xml",
              "tree": {
                "string": "Human Name",
                "field": [
                  {"name": "name"},
                  {"name": "family"},
                  {"name": "given"},
                  {"name": "prefix"}
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "model": "ir.ui.view",
          "id": "human_name_form_view",
          "field": [
            {
              "name": "name",
              "#text": "human.name.form"
            },
            {
              "name": "model",
              "#text": "human.name"
            },
            {
              "name": "arch",
              "type": "xml",
              "form": {
                "string": "Human Name Form",
                "sheet": {
                  "group": {
                    "field": [
                      {"name": "name"},
                      {"name": "family"},
                      {"name": "given"},
                      {"name": "prefix"}
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "#text": "\n\n\n        #ACTION_WINDOW_FOR_PATIENT\n        ",
      "record#1": {
        "model": "ir.actions.act_window",
        "id": "action_human_name",
        "field": [
          {
            "name": "name",
            "#text": "Human Name"
          },
          {
            "name": "res_model",
            "#text": "human.name"
          },
          {
            "name": "view_mode",
            "#text": "tree,form"
          },
          {
            "name": "help",
            "type": "html",
            "p": {
              "class": "o_view_nocontent_smiling_face",
              "#text": "Create the Human Name\n                "
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "menuitem": [
        {
          "id": "FHIR_root",
          "name": "FHIR"
        },
        {
          "id": "FHIR_human_name",
          "name": "Human Name",
          "parent": "FHIR_root",
          "action": "action_human_name"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any Python library or dedicated code to do this?

I tried building custom functions to break this out and convert them all, but, I am rather stuck in this problem.
The use case here is the code above input and the output should be the code generated by any online converter

EDIT:

```
from json2xml import json2xml
from json2xml.utils import readfromurl, readfromstring, readfromjson

data = readfromstring(string)
print(json2xml.Json2xml(data).to_xml()
```

Above code only converts a part of the json like the below code to xml:

```
    {
  "record": {
    "model": "ir.ui.view",
    "id": "address_tree_view",
    "field": [
      {
        "name": "name",
        "#text": "address.tree.view"
      },
      {
        "name": "model",
        "#text": "address"
      },
      {
        "name": "priority",
        "eval": "16"
      },
      {
        "name": "arch",
        "type": "xml",
        "tree": {
          "string": "Address",
          "field": [
            {
              "name": "text_address"
            },
            {
              "name": "address_line1"
            },
            {
              "name": "country_id"
            },
            {
              "name": "state_id"
            },
            {
              "name": "address_district"
            },
            {
              "name": "address_city"
            },
            {
              "name": "address_postal_code"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

PS: I have used the online converters but, I don't want to do that over here.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: @KlausD.I have added more, does this clear the question more?

Comment: For starters, if we broke the JSON into just record fields it would do the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dicttoxml to convert JSON directly to XML

**Installation**
pip install dicttoxml
or
easy_install dicttoxml

```
In [2]: from json import loads

In [3]: from dicttoxml import dicttoxml

In [4]: json_obj = '{"main" : {"aaa" : "10", "bbb" : [1,2,3]}}'

In [5]: xml = dicttoxml(loads(json_obj))

In [6]: print(xml)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><root><main type="dict"><aaa type="str">10</aaa><bbb type="list"><item type="int">1</item><item type="int">2</item><item type="int">3</item></bbb></main></root>

In [7]: xml = dicttoxml(loads(json_obj), attr_type=False)

In [8]: print(xml)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><root><main><aaa>10</aaa><bbb><item>1</item><item>2</item><item>3</item></bbb></main></root>
```

For more information check [here](https://github.com/quandyfactory/dicttoxml)

Answer (score 1):

try`dicttoxml` libary

if you are retrieving data from a JSON file

```
import json
import dicttoxml

with open("file_name.json", "r") as j:
    data = json.load(j);

xml = dicttoxml.dicttoxml(data)
print(xml)
```